# OpenCV - Disable all pixel alteration when saving as JPEG

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, jpeg

I'm writing a utility for Least Significant Bit (LSB) steganography in Python (2 and 3 compatability) with the OpenCV-Python package (`opencv-python==3.2.0.8`). It seems to work flawlessly with numerous PNG files that I've tested, but what I've noticed is that, seemingly no matter what, JPEG files have their pixels altered every time I call `cv2.imwrite`. Here's the `save` method for my `LSBCodec` class:

```
class LSBCodec(object):
    # ...

    def save(self, filename):
        ext = filename.split(".")[-1].lower()  # assumptions made 
        if ext in ("jpg", "jpeg", "jpe"):
            args = [[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100]]
        elif ext in ("png",):
            args = [[int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION), 0]]
        else:
            args = []
        cv2.imwrite(filename, self.img, *args)
```

However, it still alters pixels. Altering them by even one bit completely throws off the entire program (since the least significant bits are used for data and metadata storage).

For example, the first 3 bits should either be all 0's or all 1's and determine if a simple XOR key should be provided for decoding the data. The second 3 bits determine the number of least significant bits to use for the following data. Using 2 bits and no XOR key, the value encoded should be `0b000010` (but stored reversed) spread out over the first two pixels (6 channels).

**Original First 2 Pixels:**
`[ 44 120 216], [ 43 119 215]` Last Bits: 000111

**Encoded First 2 Pixels:**
`[ 44 121 216], [ 42 118 214]` Last Bits: 010000 (reversed)

**Stored First 2 Pixels:**
`[ 44 121 217], [ 42 118 214]` Should be same as above

How can I save a JPEG file without it altering the pixels in any way? Or is this simply not feasible because of some JPEG image codec with which I am unfamiliar? Would it work if I changed the extension to PNG?

Comment: jpeg compression is lossy, whereas png uses lossless compression. by it's nature, unless you use 0% compression, encoding with jpeg will loose precision in the least significant bits

Comment: OK, understood. I tried saving images and PNG and it seems to work perfectly. I guess this question can be closed unless there's anything more to add.

Comment: jpeg also typically compresses the color more than the luminance, and I don't see any options for that in `cv2.imwrite`

Comment: theoretically if you saved with perfectly 0% compression a jpeg would be fine, but it seems 100% quality is still modifying the values ever so slightly

Comment: There is no lossless compression at 100% quality in theory. Even at that setting there will be distortions, but they will be minimal. It's in the naturate of quantising the DCT coefficients and nothing can be done about it.